# How do I put name in a option and post it?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I was wondering how I get the information VIA post from a option tag, here is my code so far and I am not sure what to do thanks.

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method = "post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
        <select>
            <option name = "rock">Rock</option>
            <option name = "paper">Paper</option>
            <option name = "scissors">Scissors</option>
        </select>
        <button type = "submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <?php
    $rock = $_POST["rock"];
    $paper = $_POST["paper"];
    $scissors = $_POST["scissors"];





    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're starting from the very beginning, you'd be better served by picking a popular [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) that fits your style and needs so you don't have to work at such a low level. Committing things to the database is then a pretty simple exercise of following the examples the framework sets out. You're going to make a lot of time-consuming and potentially dangerous mistakes otherwise. What you're wrestling with here is pretty basic, there's nothing wrong with that, but trying to learn from first principles is really hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to name the select, and have values for each option like this:

```
<select name="choice">
    <option value= "rock">Rock</option>
    <option value= "paper">Paper</option>
    <option value= "scissors">Scissors</option>
</select>
```

And:

```
$pick = $_POST['choice']
```

Also note that leaving the action field blank will automatically post back to the same page

```
<form method = "post" action="">
```